# How can I group data in datawindow

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datawindow

I want to create a report on which data shows in group. I have tried but the report is not made as I require. If a number of rows have the same value, then data should be printed only one time.

```
name category value
FCL  1        3
FCL  1        9
FCL  1        3
FCL  2        2
FCL  2        5
gpl  3        13
gpl  3        15
gpl  1        10
gpl  1        3
```

but data should print

```
name category value
                  3
    1               9
FCL   ---------         3
    2           2
                5
----------------       13
    3          15
gpl   ----------       10
    1           3
```

For clarification, here is a link: [Image report](https://www.google.ae/search?newwindow=1&es_sm=93&biw=1366&bih=645&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=datain%20table%20show%20in%20group%20sub%20group&oq=datain%20table%20show%20in%20group%20sub%20group&gs_l=img.3...96403.98838.0.99087.10.10.0.0.0.0.184.1378.2j8.10.0....0...1c.1.43.img..10.0.0.aRVrDacADe8#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=SUGDWIRW4CavaM%253A;33wOd26u6IlWLM;http%253A%252F%252Fi.technet.microsoft.com%252Fdynimg%252FIC574389.gif;http%253A%252F%252Ftechnet.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Flibrary%252Fms170712.aspx;443;371)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are looking at the "Rows / Suppress repeating values" menu from the datawindow design painter.

It will hide verticaly repeated values from the selected fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the group by in powerbuilder. 
Open your datawindow object. And choose which column you want to do group by. Go to Rows Menu in the menu bar. Click the Create Group Option. 
Drag the group by column from left side to right side. And then press ok 
Now drag the columns which are all you want under that group. 
Thats it


Regards 
Raj~

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String w_band; Long w_TabPos, w_row
w_band = GetBandAtPointer ( )
w_TabPos = Pos(w_band,'~t',1)
if  w_TabPos>0 then     w_row = Long(Mid (w_band,w_TabPos+1))
If w_row > 0 Then //Your corde
```